# How to implement a custom search remote data for each column on material-tale in React

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, material-table

I was wondering if it is possible to implement a custom search row for each column in my material-table data in React ?
[image]

I would like to have a function which calls my Django Rest api's search function with the data submitted in my search filter in material-table and then display only the matched data.

Based on the material-table docs I tried to implement `customFilterAndSearch` and pass the `term` to a custom method which calls my Rest api with the search term but the `customFilterAndSearch` access the method multiple times. Actually I get to a point where there axios get method get called by the number of rows items I have in my table.

Here is the custom `customFilterAndSearch` call:

`customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) =>  this.getDataFilterNomService(term, rowData) },`

Here is my custom method I used:

```
async getDataFilterNomService(term, rowData){
    console.log("TermDinFilter", term)
    //console.log("rowDataDinFilter", rowData)
    try{
      let response = await axiosInstance.get('get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/', {
        params: {
          "nom_service":term
        }
      });
      console.log("Response la Filtru NomService", response)

    } catch(error){
        console.log("Error: ", JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
        throw error;
    }

  }
```

And here is how django gets called when I try to search for a name like : "Viorel"

```
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:02] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:03] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:04] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:04] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:04] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:04] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:05] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?nom_service=Viorel HTTP/1.1" 200 968
backend_1   | [11/Jun/2020 16:49:05] "GET /api/get/servicecatalog/filterNomService/?
```

It gets called like 18 times...as per the number of entries on the table.

I was wondering if there is a way to override the `customFilterAndSearch`...so when the user enters a submit action the Django Api gets called only one time ?

Or if there is another way of implementing this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the [blog](https://medium.com/@cristi26.gabor/how-to-implement-a-custom-column-search-in-react-material-table-with-django-rest-framework-5d085c46d6eb) and I think it can be improved. (correct me if iam wrong as iam new to this). The approach i have used to solve this issue is by using filter headers which I think is better than having a fixed row for this.
step 1: set the filtering to true

```
  options={{
    filtering: true
  }}
```

step 2: then use column specific filter rendering (you can have it as text, select , search... components). use Onchange,onBlur... to trigger the api call for remote data.

```
 columns = [ {
  field: 'one',
  title: 'One',
  filterComponent: (metaData) => {
    return (
      <input
        type='text'
        onBlur={e => {
          // console metaData and use it as per your wish
        }}
      />
    )
  }
},
{
  field: 'two',
  title: 'Two',
  filtering: false // if you dont want to have filter for any column -add this
}]
```

Comment: Hey.. Yes, your solution to have a fixed header rather than a fixed row is better. I had a lot of problems when I implemented pagination because one row more broke the pagination counters. In the meantime, I have renounced the implementation of the material table for my application but I will accept your answer since it seems as a viable solution. I am sure somebody will be grateful for your help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually... I succeeded in making it work by adding a new row with custom fields - I wrote a [post](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/5d085c46d6eb) on how I did it...maybe it will help someone.